# Syntax issues within my script

Tags: php, curl, syntax

Alright so I am just starting to learn cURL and I am having a really hard time with this at the moment I am not sure if I am just not understanding something properly or if it's just not working at all..

```
//objekt array
$TStringError = array(
'storeId'   => 'ID',
'items'             => 'ID',
'pType'             => 'PType'
);
```

I am not sure if when writing curl if I am suppose to fill out the fields or have it echo it into another location.. I am going off of a forum post and the guy did not explain it very well at all.

```
$cookies = array(
//detta ar dina inkops cookies
'anx'           => 'UniqueCookie'
);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,
//begagnade cookies ga hit
"Användar Cookies Go Here"
```

It's suppose to work along the lines of me checking out an item from my own store using curl how ever.. it's not working like that at all I am just getting error after error after error and not completely sure how to fix it.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/purchased");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
//objekt array
$TStringError = array(
'storeId'   => 'ID',
'items'             => 'ID',
'pType'             => 'PType'
);
$cookies = array(
//detta ar dina inkops cookies
'anx'           => 'UniqueCookie'
);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookies);
//begagnade cookies ga hit
"Användar Cookies Go Here"

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $TStringError);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($output);
print_r($xml,1);
echo("done\n");
echo($output);
```

This is currently my entire code how ever this code is giving me multiple errors

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $TStringError);
```

Is giving me an error with T-Strings how ever I have searched my code multiple times and see no issues with it at all.

Edit:

This is the exact error that it's giving me.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a9428267/public_html/testing.php on line 24
```

Line 24 is

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: "An error with T-Strings" Please post the full error message, exactly as it appears. It probably comes with a file and line number, too: indicate that part of your code for us. (But note that you're missing a closing bracket on one of your curl_setopt calls, for CURLOPT_COOKIE, so maybe fix that first.)

Comment: @MattGibson I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,
//begagnade cookies ga hit
"Användar Cookies Go Here"       <-- you're missing ); here to close the function call

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $TStringError);
```

Because you don't close the function, it continues looking for the `)` character or a `,` for a new parameter, and unexpectedly finds the string `curl_setopt` after 2 lines.

Comment: Even after I added in `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookies);` closing that function it's still giving me the exact same error.